# If you gain a double-9s effect from two different sources, do they stack?

Tags: stacking, exalted, exalted-3e

If my character has an artifact that gives them double-9s on Performance rolls, then uses *Impassioned Orator Technique* to grant himself double-9s from a Charm, what happens? Does that give their roll double-8s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The books don't say anything regarding two double# effects applying to the same roll. I would interpret this to mean that it does not stack, the better double# effect supersedes any lower ones.

My reasoning is that most rolls already benefit from Double 10s and all effects granting lower Double# effects don't knowledge the previous state of any of the rolls they are modifying.

If you look at the charm **Leap From Cloaking Shadows** on p.433 in the core book it treats the effects of Double 7s, 8s and 9s as completely distinct effects.

> For example, a Strength 5 Tiger stylist made an unexpected attack against an enemy who withdrew on her last turn; she could double up to three 9s, three 8s, and three 7s.

See also **Vindictive Concubine’s Pillow Book** on p.459 where the results Doubled are lowered for each condition successful met instead of being phrased as if it were stacking.

I couldn't find a specific example but there is nothing saying that a "if already double 9s, double 8s instead" effect couldn't exist in the system.